# Issues interacting with Windows Shares without mounting

Tags: mount, curl, smb, kubernetes

I am rebuilding a legacy system using Kubernetes, and do in some cases need to read and write files to Windows shares.

I have tried working with our internal cloud providers to install various drivers on the cluster to mount Windows shares but have been unable to succeed.

So far I have been able to read and write files using either the command function of smbclient or curl, but both of these methods, while working, seems to be very slow compared to a mounted alternative (testing done outside of the Kubernetes cluster). Transfer speed seems to be about half or even worse compared to mounting.

```
smbclient -U user%pass '//server/share' -m smb3 -c 'get bigfile.csv bigfile.csv'
```

and

```
curl -u "WORKGROUP\user:pass" smb://server/share/bigfile.csv > bigfile.csv
```

So, my question now is:

Is there anyway to speed up smbclient or curl when loading files over SAMBA shares or are there any other method of interacting with SAMBA shares without mounting that I am missing? Or, will unmounted access to this service always be slower due to the nature of the setup?

Comment: There are few that will be confident that they know the **Fastest way**. And in what way fast, for you?, for the computer?, or something else? And For one file or for many?

Comment: Fastest would in this case mean transfer speed, and if possible with as little overhead with authentication as possible.